# Как найти все теги img в определенном блоке div. Beautiful Soup. Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, парсер, beautiful-soup, bs4

Подскажите, пожалуйста.

Есть HTML:

```html
<div class="mw-body-content" id="bodyContent">
<img alt="" class="thumbborder" data-file-height="600">
</div>
```

Как я могу достать все `img` именно в данном диве `id="bodyContent"` с помощью Beautiful Soup?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решение через css-селектор

Например:

```
...
root = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
for img_el in root.select('#bodyContent > img'):
    print(img_el)
```

Если `img` могут быть не только прямыми детьми `id="bodyContent"`, т.е. на разных уровнях вложенности, то без `>`: `#bodyContent img`